# Equation of Plane in a unit cube given the normal and volume enclosed

Tags: geometry

I know the normal and volume enclosed by the plane. I am interested in finding out the equation of the plane. The volume enclosed is with respect to origin. The plane can have any random orientation.How should I approach this problem ?

$ n_xx+n_yy+n_zz + d =0 $

How can I calculate the 'd' ?

[image]

Comment: You can integrate the cross-sectional areas of the intersections of parallel planes, but that is not a trivial exercise since the cross-sections of the cube parallel to a given plane can be triangles, rectangles, pentagons or hexagons.   https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aSokFEpoJFM

Comment: @JohnWaylandBales Thanks for this... Will check it out